# How to share/distribute compiled for Blackberry 10 and Windows 8 mobile development

Tags: windows, package, blackberry-10, software-distribution

I would like to write some QtC++(BB10) and C#(Windows 8 Mobile) code for distribution.

What is the best way to package up the output. In Java(Android) one can package up the code in a JAR file and distribute that.

What would be the equivalent in BB10 and Windows 8 mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BlackBerry 10, you can use standard shared objects (`.so` files) or archives (`.a` files). They are standard C/C++ libraries.

On Windows 8/Windows Phone 8, using C#, you can create a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx).